# PHP: Generate code from abstraction (xml, json, data base, ...)

Tags: php, code-generation, dsl, abstraction, model-driven-development

***Note** Feel free to suggest a better title as I think 'generate code' and 'abstraction' might not be the best expressions for what I want to ask :)*

I'm looking for a **good pattern/standard way** to generate PHP code from some sort of abstraction layer.

### Example

I've built a set of classes that act es text-processing filters. These filters can be chained together to transform some input-text into some other output text, e.g.

```
Input "Hello 'CRUEL' World" 
>> RegexFilter('(.*?)') [extract everything between '']
>> ToLowerFilter [lowercase the extracted text]
Output: cruel
```

**Resulting Code**

The corresponding source code looks something like this:

```
$input = "Hello 'CRUEL' world";
$pattern = "#(.*?)#";
$first = new RegexFilter($pattern);
$second = new ToLowerFilter();
$first->setNextFilter($second);
$ouput = $first->Transform($input);
echo $output; // cruel
```

I would like to create some sort of *abstraction layer*, so that the end user (non-programmer) can built his own filter chain without writing code by himself. By "abstraction" I mean something like XML, JSON, stored in a database, etc.

**XML example (suggestion)**

```
<filters>
 <filter name='Regex'>
  <properties>
   <property name='pattern'>'(.*)'</property>
  </properties>
  <nextfilter name='ToLower'>
   <properties/>
  </filter>
 </filter>
</filters>
```

**Remark**: The example is very simplistic. Think of more advanced things like "complex objects as properties for filters", "inheritance of filters" (the above filter could get the name "RegexToLowerFilter" and can be referenced by other filters), etc.

**Approaches / Ideas**

Is there standard way to tackle this sort of problem? So far I've thought of building a custom XML, JSON, etc. serializer/deserializer for every filter but that seems like a lot of work and is potentially error prone because it's done individually for every filter. Further I guess that would require to make *every possible dependency* also serilizable in the same fashion - which can be problematic when using third party libraries (e.g. [JsonPath](https://github.com/Peekmo/JsonPath/)).

I suppose the most elegant way would be the creation of [Domain Specific Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_programming_language). Unfortunately building a compiler is not the easiest task and probably not always appropriate for every problem in that space. (Then again, feel free to correct me :))

**TL;DR**

I'm looking for a suitable way / pattern to built an abstraction layer between the (non-progammer) end user and my source code. The solution should take the "simplified" abstraction and "generate" the corresponding code.

Comment: ...so you want to allow non-programmers the ability to generate their own code on your server?

Comment: Only to a subset of predefined classes - using some simplified format (not 'real' code)

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is called "Model Driven Development"

Take a look at the various open source sub-projects in the Eclipse model-to-text (M2T) project.  My favorite is JET, but there are others with different specification and runtime characteristics.

Despite the fact that I'm a really big fan of using model driven development to solve these kinds of problems in general, I want to caution you about using these technologies (or your own implementation) to solve this specific problem.  If your target audience is really a group of non-programmers then they will have just as much trouble learning your DSL (syntax and keywords) as they would the original language you're trying to hide. The comparison (DSL vs original language) gets worse if there are development tools (debuggers, editors, etc.) for the original language. Model driven technologies tend to be more successful when applied to more expert developers who need their work automated than when applied to less expert developers looking for a miracle.

Comment: In the best case, the user doesn't even have to see any code/xml/json/etc. The full process should look something like this: User can drag & drop filters on the UI and save his "model" in XML/JSON/to the DB. My "framework" picks it up and figures out how to generate the corresponding code from that. Does this make sense?